# Git - resolved rebase conflicts then carried on working - how to save work?

Tags: git

I just resolved a large merge conflict while rebasing.  The sequence of commands was:

```
git rebase origin/develop
git mergetool
```

Once all conflicts were resolved, I would usually run:

```
git rebase --continue
```

... but I forgot to do it.

I then went around making a bunch of changes to the working directory, thinking I was starting from a clean working directory as normal (as though the rebase were complete).

To make matters more confusing, I then accidentally invoked a script I have set up for transferring working directory changes to a virtual machine.  The commands applied on the host (where I'm working) were:

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'temp'
git format-patch HEAD~
git reset HEAD~1
```

So the whole sequence is this:

[clean working dir on branch HEAD]

```
git rebase origin/develop
```

[conflicts displayed, including locally deleted/remotely modified files]

```
git mergetool
```

[conflicts resolved but **no** `git rebase --continue`]

[more changes to working dir including adding and deleting files]

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'temp'
git format-patch HEAD~
git reset HEAD~1
```

Is there any way of getting back from this?  I want to keep both the conflict resolution and my subsequent working dir changes.  I'm particularly interested in exactly what state Git is in, when the conflicts are resolved but you have not yet run `git rebase --continue`; and what `git rebase --continue` actually does.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is actually quite simple to resolve this situation.  After the `git mergetool`, I had the whole original HEAD commit, plus conflict resolutions, waiting in the staging area.  I think `git rebase --continue` at this point would have simply committed them in the same way as `git commit`.

Instead, I made some more changes, then ran the script:

```
git add -A # add more changes to the staging area
git commit -m 'temp' # do a regular commit instead of continuing the rebase
# at this point the HEAD (temp) contains all the changes I want
git format-patch HEAD~ # irrelevant, no effect
git reset HEAD~1 # all changes in working directory
```

After that I just ran:

```
git add -A
git commit -m all
```

Upon inspection, the HEAD (all) seems to have the original commit with conflicts resolved, as well as the subsequent changes.